# To apply .delay() on mouseenter in my plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a div, that on mouseenter, is suppose to show another div. I'm not sure how to achive this in a plugin. This is my code and what I have tried so far.

Code: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FwRBd/)

```
<div class="hover-me"></div>
<div class="show-me"></div>

    var Nav = {
        hover_me: $('.hover-me'),
        show_me: $('.show-me'),

    init: function() {
        Nav.toggle_display();
        console.log('init');
    },

    toggle_display: function() {
        Nav.hover_me.mouseenter(function() {
            Nav.show();
        });

        Nav.hover_me.mouseleave(function () {
            Nav.hide();
        });
    },

    show: function() {
        Nav.show_me.fadeIn();
    },

    hide: function() {
        Nav.show_me.fadeOut();
    }
};
```

I tried to do this, without any luck.

```
Nav.hover_me.mouseenter(function() {
      Nav.delay(1000).show();
 });
```

Comment: You could just wrap `Nav.show();` within a `setTimeout` with 1000 as a parameter?

Comment: No then it will show regardless after 1 second. I want to show the second div only if the user hovers on the div for 1 second

Comment: btw, it is not plugin it is just object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see Jimbo's comment:

```
var Nav = {
    // [...]
    timeoutId: undefined,
    // [...]
};

Nav.hover_me.mouseenter(function() {
    Nav.timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        Nav.show();
    }, 1000);
});

Nav.hover_me.mouseleave(function () {
    if (Nav.timeoutId) { clearTimeout(Nav.timeoutId); }
    Nav.hide();
});
```

SEE THE [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/algorhythm/FwRBd/4/)

Comment: No then it will show the div regardless after 1 second. I want to show the second div only if the user hovers on the div for 1 second, thats why i want the delay

Comment: @Dejan.S Then clear the timeout when the `mouseleave` event fires. The `.delay()` jQuery function is **not** designed to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks that will work, just so i understand this, the timeout gets a bool or int value?

Comment: setTimeout generates an ID and with this ID you can stop the running timeout with clearTimeout(ID)... The second parameter is the delay to wait as integer.